# Spring Boot - Cloud Configuration and Docker

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and evaluating the same for building microservice-based application in my organisation.
I have gone through many examples and I see that most of them are tightly coupled with Docker. I understand, each microservice is being run as a new instance. But, if I am working on Windows, and don't want to go the Docker way, does Spring Cloud as a whole really makes sense. Please help me if I am missing out on something.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong samples. Nothing ties you to docker or whatever technology. Heck they are just executable jar files which you can just run, no need for docker or whatever technology. So instead of looking at 1 or 2 samples read the documentation.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply. I understand Docker is just an instance running your microservices. So, if I want to bring down one microservice, I can restart a Docker instance with the upgraded version as per my requirement. I have a basic question here, currently, we have a war deployed on tomcat. If I need to replace this implementation, how would I deploy microservices in a real production environment without docker. It requires a container , right. Do we have to use tomcat, and convert each microservices to wars and deploy it on tomcat. Do you think I am missing out on some basics. Thanks

Comment: Yes you are missing some basics. Do you need a container that depends on your microservice. Do you need docker, do you need tomcat no. It all depends.